# How to insert opening brace and matcing brace in vim manually

Tags: vim, plugins

I am using autopairs plugin.

```
if(num==5)//if i delete here the matching brace then further i couldn't add matching brace.
```

I want to also add opening brace.. But it's giving me pair of brace.
     int main()
    {

```
}//if i delete this brace further i also can't add this...
if(abs()(num*5))//here after abs i want to add only opening brace
//but here coming two.
```

I am new in vim.. If anyone could elaborately describe the solution then it would be huge help for me..

Comment: https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/issues/133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd. Usually, bracket plugins let us insert a closing brackets when it's not the next character under the cursor. otherwise, you can always inhibit the mapping on demand by pressing CTRL-V before the closing bracket key.